# Ehcache: Unable to find cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I am using Ehcache+Spring+Hibernte in my application here are some detail information
Getting below exception

> Caused by: com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.CacheNotFoundException:
>   Unable to find cache 'com.ccc.spring.model.Validuserrole'     at
>   com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl.getCache(CacheAttributeSourceImpl.java:223)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl.parseCacheableAnnotation(CacheAttributeSourceImpl.java:325)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl.findMethodAttribute(CacheAttributeSourceImpl.java:268)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl.computeMethodAttribute(CacheAttributeSourceImpl.java:242)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl.getMethodAttribute(CacheAttributeSourceImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl.getAdviceType(CacheAttributeSourceImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut.matches(CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut.java:46)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:376)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:339)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     ... 21 more

Here is my ehcache.xml file

```
<ehcache>

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="200" />
    <cache name="com.ccc.spring.model.Validuserrole" maxElementsInMemory="100"
        eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="5" timeToLiveSeconds="2000" />

</ehcache>
```

applicationContext.xml file entry

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven />

    <ehcache:config cache-manager="cacheManager">
        <ehcache:evict-expired-elements
            interval="60" />
    </ehcache:config>

    <bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" />

    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ccc.spring" />
```

and in DAO i am using below code

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="com.ccc.spring.model.Validuserrole")
    public List<Validuserrole> getRoleList() {
        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Validuserrole where active = ?")
                .setParameter(0, true).list();
        return list;
    }
```

But still sating cache not found.

**EDIT**

```
@Cacheable( value = { "com.ccc.spring.model.Validuserrole" })
    public List<Validuserrole> getRoleList() {
        List list = null;
        try{
          list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Validuserrole ").list();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

ANOTHER EDIT

```
Hibernate: select validuserr0_.roleid as roleid15_, validuserr0_.active as active15_, validuserr0_.createdon as createdon15_, validuserr0_.roledescription as roledesc4_15_ from subodhc_ccc.validuserrole validuserr0_
Hibernate: select user0_.userid as userid11_, user0_.aboutme as aboutme11_, user0_.addressid as addressid11_, user0_.createdon as createdon11_, user0_.dikshadate as dikshadate11_, user0_.dob as dob11_, user0_.emailid as emailid11_, user0_.firstname as firstname11_, user0_.gender as gender11_, user0_.lastmodifiedby as lastmodi9_11_, user0_.lastmodifiedon as lastmod10_11_, user0_.lastname as lastname11_, user0_.middlename as middlename11_, user0_.mobilenumber as mobilen13_11_, user0_.password as password11_, user0_.phonenumber as phonenu15_11_, user0_.username as username11_, user0_.statusid as statusid11_, user0_.roleid as roleid11_ from subodhc_ccc.user user0_ where user0_.statusid=2 and user0_.roleid=4
Hibernate: select country0_.CountryId as CountryId2_, country0_.CountryName as CountryN2_2_, country0_.LastUpdate as LastUpdate2_ from subodhc_ccc.country country0_
Hibernate: select validuserr0_.roleid as roleid15_, validuserr0_.active as active15_, validuserr0_.createdon as createdon15_, validuserr0_.roledescription as roledesc4_15_ from subodhc_ccc.validuserrole validuserr0_
Hibernate: select country0_.CountryId as CountryId2_, country0_.CountryName as CountryN2_2_, country0_.LastUpdate as LastUpdate2_ from subodhc_ccc.country country0_
```

Comment: I think you are using the wrong caching annotations. Make sure that `@Cacheable` is imported from `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable`. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: i am using import com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable

Comment: Make the change I mentioned in the previous comment, and let me know what happens. Spring's caching support has nothing to do with Google caching support

Comment: It worked but i am using this example http://www.tuicool.com/articles/zInIJ3 Do you have any good example for Integration Spring+Hibernate+Ehcache

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the wrong annotations for Spring + EhCache integration. You need to use `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable` instead of `com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable`.

Check out [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-caching-and-ehcache) and [this](http://blog.goyello.com/2012/01/20/quick-start-with-methods-caching-using-spring-3-1-and-ehcache/) for more information about how to use Spring's caching support (introduced with Spring 3.1) and EhCache as the caching provider

Comment: I have to use which attribute value or something else to save cache with some name  @Cacheable( value = { "com.ccc.spring.model.Validuserrole" })

Comment: What you described should work, since the value of the annotation is the name of the cache.

Comment: Edit question added new method also But its not working its again fetching record from DB

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the blog posts correctly?

Comment: Yes maximum thing are same,added query as well

Comment: Any idea on this issue?

Comment: You tried renaming the cache to something without `.`?

Comment: Yes   @Cacheable( value = "ValidUserRole" )
 and in ehcache.xml cache name="ValidUserRole"

Comment: Does the class that has `@Cacheable` implement an interface or not?

Comment: No any implementation Just used @Cacheable( value = "ValidUserRole" ) above my GteuserList menthod

Comment: You need to make sure that the class that has `GteuserList` is a Spring Bean and then also add `cglib` to your classpath

Comment: getUserList() is a method in CommonDAO.java which is define in applicationcontext.xml file also cglib already added in pom.xml file

Comment: Is your code shareable? I can't think of any thing else off hand, but I would be willing to try to debug it

Comment: i can send you those file or demo thing

Comment: I would need something that is runnable in order to test it

Comment: Tell me your id i will send you

Comment: It's probably best that you upload to some file sharing or github and post it to your answer so other users can find it as well

Answer (score 0):

Implement Serializable interface in your bean
and write  `diskStore path="F:/ehcache"/>` in your `ehcache.xml` file

Comment: but how this will work when we have to deploy project into production server ?